# MLP with sliding windows = TDNN

Tags: neural-network

Need some confirmation on the statement.

Is two of these equivalent?
1.MLP with sliding time windows
2.Time delay neural network (TDNN)

Can anyone confirm on the given statement? Possibly with reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Equivalent" is too generalizing but you can roughly say that in terms of architecture (at least regarding their original proposal - there have been more modifications like the MS-TDNN which is even more different from a MLP). The correct phrasing would be that *TDNN is an extended MLP architecture* [[1]](http://wwwipr.ira.uka.de/get.php?id=48).

Both use Backpropagation and both are FeedForward nets. 
The main idea can probably be phrased like this:

> Delaying the inputs of neurons located in a hidden or the output layer
>   is similar to multiplying the layers beyond and helps with pattern
>   scaling and translation and is close to integrating the input signal
>   over time.

What makes it different from the MLP:

> However, in order to deal with delayed or scaled input signals, the
>   original denition of the TDNN required that all (delayed) links of a
>   neuron that are connected to one input are identical.

This requirement was overthrown in later studies, however, like in [[1]](http://wwwipr.ira.uka.de/get.php?id=48) where past and present nodes have different weights (which obviously seems reasonable for a number of applications) making it equivalent of a MLP.

That's all regarding architecture comparisons. Let's talk about training. The results will be different: The whole training will differ if you input the same sequential data into an MLP wich only gets *current data one-by-one* from a sliding window and if you input it *with current and past data* together into the TDNN. The big difference is **context**. With the MLP you'll have the context of past inputs in **past activations**. With the TDNN you'll have them in **present activations**, directly coupled to your present inputs. Again, MLPs have no temporal context capabilities (this is why recurrent neural networks are much more popular for sequential data) and the TDNN is an attempt to solve that. The way I see it, TDNN is basically an attempt to merge the 2 worlds of MLPs (basic Backprop) and RNNs (context/sequences).

**TL;DR:** If you strip down the TDNNs purpose you can say your statement holds true on an architectural level. But if you compare both architectures side by side in action you will get different observations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is decription of TDNN taken from [Waibel et al 1989 paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/waibelTDNN.pdf). "In our TDNN basic unit is modified by intoducing delays D1 through Dn as shown in Fig. 1. J inputs of such unit now will be multiplied by several weights, one for each delay". This is essentialy MLP with sliding window (see also Fig. 2 there).